# Remove columns from file bash tools

Tags: linux, bash, awk

I have a large file with about 200,000 columns and about 5000 rows.
Here is a short example of the file, with columns 1 and 5 duplicated.

```
Abf Bgj Csd Daa Abf Efg ...  
0   1   2   1   0   1.1   
2   0.1 1.2 0.3 2   1    
...
```

Here is an example of the result I need. Column 5 in the original file has been deleted.

```
Abf Bgj Csd Daa Efg ...  
0   1   2   1   1.1    
2   0.1 1.2 0.3 1      
...
```

Some of the columns are duplicated several times.
I need to remove the duplicates from the data (keeping the first instance) using bash tools.
I can´t sort the data because I need to keep the order.

Comment: format your question and show the desired output

Comment: Do you need compare each column values or only column headers will be sufficient? For example, can file contain different columns with same `Abf` header? That is, exist two ways: 1) traverse through the file and remove all columns with the same header and 2) traverse through the file and remove all identical columns with the same header and values.

Comment: I only need to compare column headers.

Answer (score 5):

```
$ cat tst.awk
NR==1 {
    for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {
        if (!seen[$i]++) {
            f[++nf]=i
        }
    }
}
{
    for (i=1;i<=nf;i++) {
        printf "%s%s", $(f[i]), (i<nf?OFS:ORS)
    }
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file | column -t
Abf  Bgj  Csd  Daa  Efg
0    1    2    1    1.1
2    0.1  1.2  0.3  1
```

Comment: This works and does exactly what I needed. Could you please explain how this block of code works ?

Comment: What part of it don't you understand?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `datamash` program:

```
datamash -W transpose < input.txt | datamash rmdup 1 | datamash transpose
```

> GNU [datamash](https://www.gnu.org/software/datamash/) is a command-line program which performs basic
>   numeric,textual and statistical operations on input textual data
>   files.

**Explanation:**

1. `datamash -W transpose < input.txt`

   - **transpose** - swap rows and columns. Rows now are columns and columns are rows.
   - **-W** - use whitespace (one or more spaces and/or tabs) for field delimiters.
2. `datamash rmdup 1` - remove duplicates lines by the first column value
3. `datamash transpose` - swap rows and columns back

**input**

```
Abf Bgj Csd Daa Abf Efg
0   1   2   1   0   1.1   
2   0.1 1.2 0.3 2   1
```

**output**

```
Abf Bgj Csd Daa Efg
0   1   2   1   1.1
2   0.1 1.2 0.3 1
```